# Consultas no Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando executar uma consulta no `Laravel`, no terminal funciona perfeitamente, porém quando insiro no `Laravel`, a mesma me retorna vazio, exemplo:

***Consulta:***

```
   SELECT 
    MAX(positions.id),
    devices.name,
    positions.deviceid,
    positions.servertime,
    positions.devicetime,
    positions.fixtime,
    positions.latitude,
    positions.longitude
FROM positions
INNER JOIN devices 
    ON positions.deviceid = devices.id
GROUP BY positions.deviceid
```

***no*** `Laravel`:

```
$ultimasPosicoes = PositionAll::select('SELECT 
            MAX(positions.id),
            devices.name,
            positions.deviceid,
            positions.servertime,
            positions.devicetime,
            positions.fixtime,
            positions.latitude,
            positions.longitude
            FROM
            positions
            INNER JOIN devices ON positions.deviceid = devices.id
            GROUP BY
            positions.deviceid');
```

Comment: só uma dica, coloca o nome da sua model no singular, e deixe um nome que indique qual o seu papel. Ex: `Position.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `DB::table()` para fazer a consulta indicando os campos que precisa, ficaria mais ou menos dessa maneira:

```
$positions = DB::table('positions')
->selectRaw('MAX(positions.id),
    devices.name,
    positions.deviceid,
    positions.servertime,
    positions.devicetime,
    positions.fixtime,
    positions.latitude,
    positions.longitude')
->join('devices', 'positions.deviceid', '=', 'devices.id')->groupBy('deviceid')->get();
```

Outra maneira que foi comentada pelo Leandro RR é usar o `Eloquent` puro, no caso ao invés de usar a `Facade DB` passariamos a usar apenas a `Model`, ficando dessa maneira:

```
$positions = Position::selectRaw('MAX(positions.id),
        devices.name,
        positions.deviceid,
        positions.servertime,
        positions.devicetime,
        positions.fixtime,
        positions.latitude,
        positions.longitude')
    ->join('devices', 'positions.deviceid', '=', 'devices.id')
    ->groupBy('positions.deviceid')
    ->get();
```

Referencia: [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

Comment: Meu Amigão desde já gostaria de agradecer pela atenção, mais me retornou um erro Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Rastreamento\Position\DB' not found, pode me ajudar?

Comment: provavelmente você só copiou o código e não importou a classe DB

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: lembrando que se você esta usando eloquent orm pode usar o `selectRaw()` para colocar as expressões em puro dql dentro.

Comment: Tem razão @LeandroRR editei a resposta

Comment: acho que nem o DB facade precisa usar, só usar o eloquent puro mesmo, chamando a model `Position::selectRaw()` e lá na model ele declara uma variavel `protected` chamada `$table = 'positions';`

Comment: Sim sim, dessa maneira funciona também, seria apenas trocar o DB::table('positions') por Position::selectRaw ...

Answer (score 1):

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda de todos, conseguimos resolver da seguinte forma:

```
$ultimasPosicoes =  PositionAll::selectRaw('MAX(positions.id),
                                        devices.name,
                                        positions.deviceid,
                                        positions.servertime,
                                        positions.devicetime,
                                        positions.fixtime,
                                        positions.latitude,
                                        positions.longitude')
            ->join('devices', 'positions.deviceid', '=', 'devices.id')
            ->groupBy('deviceid')
            ->get();
```